# SET JAVA_HOME to reflect jenv java version

Tags: bash, java-home, jenv

I just started to use `jenv`, I followed a blog post that was explaining how to use `jenv` and setup multiple java version on MacOSX. But the problem now I am running into is setting up the JAVA_HOME. As I switch java environment using `jenv` I want to make sure `JAVA_HOME` on my bash_profile also changes accordingly.

How do i do that?

I have following on my `~/.bash_profile`

```
if which jenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(jenv init -)"; fi
```

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME already set? What is your output if you enter "jenv doctor" in the Terminal?

Answer (score 119):

Try the "export" plugin:

`jenv enable-plugin export`

You can check the Export plugin section in Readme.md at the jEnv Github repo (https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv)

Comment: Why it's not included by default?

Comment: It is working on Mac!

Answer (score 13):

For me, enabling the `export` plugin like kimbaudi didn't work. Adding the following code to `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc`, `.zprofile` or `.zshrc` depending on what shell you use) did the job for me:

```
if which jenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(jenv init -)"; fi
```

This was in the [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/jenv/jenv/wiki/Trouble-Shooting), but they seemed to state it was in the instructions guide, which it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe send in a PR to the repo? This is quite key indeed.

Comment: Thanks, works for me after added upon line into zshrc file

Answer (score 5):

You can add these alias in your `~/.bash_profile` file and easily switch between different JAVA versions.

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME’
```

- To check the available java versions in your system use

  ```
  jenv versions

  jenv version
  ```
- You can even set particular version for single project by using following command in private terminal.

  ```
  jenv local 11.0
  ```

**# Seconds option :-**

Download adopt jdk from your choise from `file -> project structure -> project sdk`
and then add following function in your .zshrc to switch between different version as per requirement.

[Attaching screenshot for reference:] :-

[image]

**Switch between different JDK versions**

Add the below function in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc

```
jdk() {
        version=$1
        export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"$version");
        java -version
 }
```

- Source the profile and you can change the version like below:

jdk 1.8
jdk 9
jdk 11
jdk 13

Answer (score 4):

(Tested with jenv 0.5.6 on macOS 13)

Set JAVA_HOME to reflect jenv java version:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(jenv javahome)
```

Note: The `javahome` command is omitted by current `jenv help`.

Comment: worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: worked with MacOS+zsh and jenv 0.5.6